# After updating android studio to 2.3 getting error "Error while Installing APKs" in MI4

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating android studio to 2.3 getting error "Error while Installing APKs" in MI4 .Working fine with Samsung Tab 3 but getting error in MI4

My  gradle looklike this

```
 applicationId "com.intellyze.letsschool"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: Invalidate Caches and Restart ..!!

Comment: wont work. i have tried restarting android studio,reinstall drivers,change minimumSdk versions

Comment: did you uninstall Previews Previous installed app from MI ?

Comment: yes i do. i have uninstall app . but same error

Comment: post your app.gradle code

Comment: @janki ,@Babul Patel thank you for your valuable time .I have solved  the issue by "Disable MIUI Optimization in Developer Settings".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Android Studio 2.3 Error for launching application on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578302/android-studio-2-3-error-for-launching-application-on-real-device/42578502#42578502)

Disable MIUI Optimization in Developer Settings

Answer (score 0):

I've had a kind of this situation.
I reinstalled android studio(project backup, uninstall, removing the rest of the files, reboot, clean install) and it worked! Try it too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not bet solution, but it work:
File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Answer (score 0):

Just reopen your project, build it and run. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Just Disable Instant Run in Android Studio,

**Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run**