# Android Studio 2.3 Error for launching application on real device

Tags: android-studio

After Updating Android Studio to 2.3, instant run not working and failed to launch application on real device

Comment: This issue is coming after updating android studio to 2.3 version

Answer (score 3):

In case you are running a device with MIUI, go to Developer Settings > Turn on MIUI optimization and turn it off.

You will then need to restart your device and recompile the code.

Instant Run should then work again

Comment: Check in option if it has any kind of optimization on Developer Settings or somewhere else. Mine was working until now as well but after the 2.3 update stopped working.

Comment: So this is not related to device i think there might be problem in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

By advising  [Issue 233579](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233579#c21) helps to disabe MIUI Optimizations in Developer Settings.